# Pythonbrew install ZSH on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, zsh, pythonbrew

Can anyone shed any light on how to have pythonbrew / pythonz install when my shell is ZSH. I am on ubuntu 12.04.

I have followed the standard install of curl and then adding the line to ~/.bashrc but it will return an unknown command in a new zsh terminal.

```
[[ -s $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc ]] && source $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc
```

[PythonBrew Readme](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew#readme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bashrc file does not work with zsh unfortunately.

Take python2.5 as an example, this seems to work:

```
sudo ~/.pythonbrew/bin/pythonbrew install 2.5
```

Then to invoke python2.5:

```
~/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.5/bin/python
```

For convenience set:

```
$PATH=$HOME/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.5/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

zsh does not read ~/.bashrc  - try putting the same code in ~/.zshrc

Comment: adding that to ~.zshrc still results in zsh not seeing pythonbrew.                     sayth@sayth-TravelMate-5740G[~]
[9:04]:pythonbrew list
zsh: correct 'pythonbrew' to '.pythonbrew' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: pythonbrew

Comment: Also tried altering the initial command  to curl -kL http://xrl.us/pythonbrewinstall | zsh  but also no go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [emulate](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) command in your zshrc.

```
emulate sh -c '[[ -s $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc ]] && . $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc'
```

I have a different setup (my emulate calls a functionrc that has functions available to bash and zsh), but I think this is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this old question:

As I write this (late 2017), `pythonbrew` is unmaintained and `pythonz` appears to be in maintenance-only mode.

At this time I would strongly suggest users switch to the actively maintained [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) instead.

And just for the record, `pyenv` fully supports bash, zsh and fish.